# URI Name spaces & WSDL files

Tags: web-services, namespaces, wsdl, uri

I am invoking a web service for my web application. It runs slow on HTTP requests from an external source.

Would this be a problem with the URI namespace defined in the WSDL file? I have noticed that the URI Namespace defined in the WSDL points to a non-existing url. Lets stay

> IN WSDL URL:
>   http://www.corrrecturl.com < spelling
>   mistake
>   CORRECT URL:
>   http://www.correcturl.com < correct
>   url

Because I cannot resolve the URL of the WSDL defined URI Namespace, would this be making the times slow?

Webservice:

- ASP 2.0
- .NET
- IIS 7

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI used in a namespace is not used as the location of a resource on a network. It is never used in an HTTP request.

You will realized this when you know that it is a UR**I**, not a UR**L**. It's an **I**dentifier, not a **L**ocator. A URI like "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:something" could not be used in an HTTP request.

Comment: No, it has to be a valid URI. But it doesn't _point_ to anything. It's used as a namespace, like a namespace in .NET.